# how can i set and display another filed in local database?

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, web-services, ionic-framework

i am trying the example todo app,i download that example in ionic and i tried that it is working, and i trued to add another filed inside newTask.html and add in local database as same as previous value,but it is not working can you please help me how can i add another filed in the local database and get results in list html file....

```
NewTask.html
------------
<div class="modal" ng-controller="newTaskCtrl">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Add New Task</h1>
        <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="closeNewTask()">Cancel</button>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
        <form ng-submit="createTask(task)">
            <div class="list">
                <!--label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Title What do you need to do?" ng-model="task.title">
                </label-->

                 <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                    <span class="input-label">Title</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="What do you need to do?" ng-model="task.title">
                     <span class="input-label">Lasr Name</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname?" ng-model="task.firstname">
                </label>
                <!--div class="row">
                <label class="col">
                    <input type="" ng-model="time">
                </label>
                <label class="col">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="End?" >
                </label>
                    </div-->
            </div>
            <div class="padding">
                <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">Create Task</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</div>

NewTaskCtrl.js
-------------------
todoApp.controller('newTaskCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicPopup, SQLService) {
    // Called when the form is submitted

    $scope.createTask = function(task) {
    SQLService.set(task.title,task.firstname);
    $scope.loadTask();
    $scope.taskModal.hide();
    task.title = "";
    task.firstname = "";
  };


SQLService.js
------------------


todoApp.factory("SQLService", function ($q) {

    var db;
    var task='';
    var deltask;

    function createDB() {
        try {
            db = window.openDatabase("todoDB", "1.0", "ToDoApp", 10*1024*1024);
            db.transaction(function(tx){
                tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title VARCHAR(100), firstname VARCHAR(100) )",[]);
            });
        } catch (err) {
            alert("Error processing SQL: " + err);
        }
        console.log('database created');
    }

    function setTasks(title,firstname){
        return promisedQuery("INSERT INTO tasks(title,firstname) VALUES ('" + title + "','" + firstname + "')", defaultResultHandler, defaultErrorHandler);
    }
     function getTasks(){
        return promisedQuery('SELECT * FROM tasks', defaultResultHandler, defaultErrorHandler);
    }

    function defaultResultHandler(deferred) {
      return function(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        var output_results = [];

        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            var t = {'id':results.rows.item(i).id,'title':results.rows.item(i).title,'firstname':results.rows.item(i).firstname};
            output_results.push(t);             
        }

        deferred.resolve(output_results);  
      }  
    }

    function defaultErrorHandler(deferred) {
      return function(tx, results) {
        var len = 0;
        var output_results = ''; 
        deferred.resolve(output_results);
      } 
    }

    function promisedQuery(query, successCB, errorCB) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql(query, [], successCB(deferred), errorCB(deferred));      
      }, errorCB);
      return deferred.promise;  
    }

    return {
        setup: function() {
          return createDB();
        },
        set: function(title,firstname) {
            return setTasks(title,firstname);
        },

        all: function() {
          return getTasks();
        }
    }
});

PLease see the SQL Service and help me,is it correct what i add the filed name in  "setTasks function.."
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you had tried the example that you had downloaded, now you have added another field in NewTask.html. But the new field that you added is not getting added to the table right??

Did you try to change the version of the DB opened??

**db = window.openDatabase("todoDB", "1.0", "ToDoApp", 10*1024*1024);**
to
**db = window.openDatabase("todoDB", "2.0", "ToDoApp", 10*1024*1024);**

Comment: thank you,...i changed the version name also but it is nor working,if i am displaying values in list,if i displayed only title in list,value is displayed,when i add another filed firstname  at that both values are not displaying in list,please help me that

Comment: can u please send me your mailid i will send the code to your mail id

Comment: shashikant.mokkarala@outlook.com